# Efecto copos de nieve con imagen

Tags: javascript, html

Con el siguiente HTML tengo el **efecto de copos de nieves** con la letra * pero desearía cambiar la letra asterisco por una imagen real, en tamaño icono.

Código HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script>

// Numero de copos, recomendados entre 30 y 40
var nieve_cantidad=70;

// Colores de los copos se mostraran de forma aleatoria
var nieve_colorr=new Array("#aaaacc","#ddddFF","#ccccDD")

// Tipo de letra de los copos
var nieve_tipo=new Array("Arial Black","Arial Narrow","Times","Comic Sans MS")

// Valor o letra de los copos
var nieve_letra="*"

// velocidad de caida
var nieve_velocidad=1.0;

// tamaño mas grande de los copos
var nieve_cantidadsize=30

// tamaño mas pequeño de los copos
var nieve_chico=8

// 1 toda la pagina - 2 zona izquierda - 3 centro de pagina - 4 zona derecha
var nieve_zona=1

var nieve=new Array()
var marginbottom
var marginright
var timer
var i_nieve=0
var x_mv=new Array();
var crds=new Array();
var lftrght=new Array();
var browserinfos=navigator.userAgent
var ie5=document.all&&document.getElementById&&!browserinfos.match(/Opera/)
var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all
var opera=browserinfos.match(/Opera/)  
var browserok=ie5||ns6||opera

function aleatorio(range) {    
    rand=Math.floor(range*Math.random())
    return rand
}

function initnieve() {
    if (ie5 || opera) {
        marginbottom = document.body.clientHeight
        marginright = document.body.clientWidth
    }
    else if (ns6) {
        marginbottom = window.innerHeight
        marginright = window.innerWidth
    }
    var nievesizerange=nieve_cantidadsize-nieve_chico
    for (i=0;i<=nieve_cantidad;i++) {
        crds[i] = 0;                      
        lftrght[i] = Math.random()*15;        
        x_mv[i] = 0.03 + Math.random()/10;
        nieve[i]=document.getElementById("s"+i)
        nieve[i].style.fontFamily=nieve_tipo[aleatorio(nieve_tipo.length)]
        nieve[i].size=aleatorio(nievesizerange)+nieve_chico
        nieve[i].style.fontSize=nieve[i].size
        nieve[i].style.color=nieve_colorr[aleatorio(nieve_colorr.length)]
        nieve[i].sink=nieve_velocidad*nieve[i].size/5
        if (nieve_zona==1) {nieve[i].posx=aleatorio(marginright-nieve[i].size)}
        if (nieve_zona==2) {nieve[i].posx=aleatorio(marginright/2-nieve[i].size)}
        if (nieve_zona==3) {nieve[i].posx=aleatorio(marginright/2-nieve[i].size)+marginright/4}
        if (nieve_zona==4) {nieve[i].posx=aleatorio(marginright/2-nieve[i].size)+marginright/2}
        nieve[i].posy=aleatorio(2*marginbottom-marginbottom-2*nieve[i].size)
        nieve[i].style.left=nieve[i].posx
        nieve[i].style.top=nieve[i].posy
    }
    movenieve()
}

function movenieve() {
    for (i=0;i<=nieve_cantidad;i++) {
        crds[i] += x_mv[i];
        nieve[i].posy+=nieve[i].sink
        nieve[i].style.left=nieve[i].posx+lftrght[i]*Math.sin(crds[i]);
        nieve[i].style.top=nieve[i].posy

        if (nieve[i].posy>=marginbottom-2*nieve[i].size || parseInt(nieve[i].style.left)>(marginright-3*lftrght[i])){
            if (nieve_zona==1) {nieve[i].posx=aleatorio(marginright-nieve[i].size)}
            if (nieve_zona==2) {nieve[i].posx=aleatorio(marginright/2-nieve[i].size)}
            if (nieve_zona==3) {nieve[i].posx=aleatorio(marginright/2-nieve[i].size)+marginright/4}
            if (nieve_zona==4) {nieve[i].posx=aleatorio(marginright/2-nieve[i].size)+marginright/2}
            nieve[i].posy=0
        }
    }
    var timer=setTimeout("movenieve()",50)
}

for (i=0;i<=nieve_cantidad;i++) {
    document.write("<span id='s"+i+"' style='position:absolute;top:-"+nieve_cantidadsize+"'>"+nieve_letra+"</span>")
}
if (browserok) {
    window.onload=initnieve
}
</script>
<body><br>
<br>

<div style='width:100%;height:500px;'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**¿Por qué no me funciona con iconos?** Con el siguiente icono...
var nieve_letra="*" // "imagenes/icono.jpg"

**¿Cómo podría llamarlo desde ?**
document.write(""+nieve_letra+"")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Al asignar el valor a las propiedades `left` y `top` debes indicar que la unidad son píxels:

```
    nieve[i].style.left=nieve[i].posx + 'px';
    nieve[i].style.top=nieve[i].posy + 'px';
```

```js
// Numero de copos, recomendados entre 30 y 40
var nieve_cantidad=70;

// Colores de los copos se mostraran de forma aleatoria
var nieve_colorr=new Array("#aaaacc","#ddddFF","#ccccDD")

// Tipo de letra de los copos
var nieve_tipo=new Array("Arial Black","Arial Narrow","Times","Comic Sans MS")

// Valor o letra de los copos
var nieve_letra="*"

// velocidad de caida
var nieve_velocidad=1.0;

// tamaño mas grande de los copos
var nieve_cantidadsize=30

// tamaño mas pequeño de los copos
var nieve_chico=8

// 1 toda la pagina - 2 zona izquierda - 3 centro de pagina - 4 zona derecha
var nieve_zona=1

var nieve=new Array()
var marginbottom
var marginright
var timer
var i_nieve=0
var x_mv=new Array();
var crds=new Array();
var lftrght=new Array();
var browserinfos=navigator.userAgent
var ie5=document.all&&document.getElementById&&!browserinfos.match(/Opera/)
var ns6=document.getElementById&&!document.all
var opera=browserinfos.match(/Opera/)  
var browserok=ie5||ns6||opera

function aleatorio(range) {    
    rand=Math.floor(range*Math.random())
    return rand
}

function initnieve() {
    if (ie5 || opera) {
        marginbottom = document.body.clientHeight
        marginright = document.body.clientWidth
    }
    else if (ns6) {
        marginbottom = window.innerHeight
        marginright = window.innerWidth
    }
    var nievesizerange=nieve_cantidadsize-nieve_chico
    for (i=0;i<=nieve_cantidad;i++) {
        crds[i] = 0;                      
        lftrght[i] = Math.random()*15;        
        x_mv[i] = 0.03 + Math.random()/10;
        nieve[i]=document.getElementById("s"+i)
        nieve[i].style.fontFamily=nieve_tipo[aleatorio(nieve_tipo.length)]
        nieve[i].size=aleatorio(nievesizerange)+nieve_chico
        nieve[i].style.fontSize=nieve[i].size
        nieve[i].style.color=nieve_colorr[aleatorio(nieve_colorr.length)]
        nieve[i].sink=nieve_velocidad*nieve[i].size/5
        if (nieve_zona==1) {nieve[i].posx=aleatorio(marginright-nieve[i].size)}
        if (nieve_zona==2) {nieve[i].posx=aleatorio(marginright/2-nieve[i].size)}
        if (nieve_zona==3) {nieve[i].posx=aleatorio(marginright/2-nieve[i].size)+marginright/4}
        if (nieve_zona==4) {nieve[i].posx=aleatorio(marginright/2-nieve[i].size)+marginright/2}
        nieve[i].posy=aleatorio(2*marginbottom-marginbottom-2*nieve[i].size)
        nieve[i].style.left=nieve[i].posx + 'px';
        nieve[i].style.top=nieve[i].posy + 'px';
    }
    movenieve()
}

function movenieve() {
    for (i=0;i<=nieve_cantidad;i++) {
        crds[i] += x_mv[i];
        nieve[i].posy+=nieve[i].sink
        nieve[i].style.left=nieve[i].posx+lftrght[i]*Math.sin(crds[i]) + 'px';;
        nieve[i].style.top=nieve[i].posy + 'px';

        if (nieve[i].posy>=marginbottom-2*nieve[i].size || parseInt(nieve[i].style.left)>(marginright-3*lftrght[i])){
            if (nieve_zona==1) {nieve[i].posx=aleatorio(marginright-nieve[i].size)}
            if (nieve_zona==2) {nieve[i].posx=aleatorio(marginright/2-nieve[i].size)}
            if (nieve_zona==3) {nieve[i].posx=aleatorio(marginright/2-nieve[i].size)+marginright/4}
            if (nieve_zona==4) {nieve[i].posx=aleatorio(marginright/2-nieve[i].size)+marginright/2}
            nieve[i].posy=0
        }
    }
    var timer=setTimeout("movenieve()",50)
}

for (i=0;i<=nieve_cantidad;i++) {
    document.write("<span id='s"+i+"' style='position:absolute;top:-"+nieve_cantidadsize+"'>"+nieve_letra+"</span>")
}
if (browserok) {
    window.onload=initnieve
}
```